# Send an android Intent with an POJO as an Intent extra?

Tags: java, android

Is their a way to put a POJO inside the intent.putExtra?

I have looked into the API's and it only seems to support of type string, int, double, boolean etc but not a actual POJO/regular java object.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a POJO as long as it implements `Serializable` or `Parcelable`.  Take a look at `intent.putExtra(String, Serializable)` or `intent.putExtra(String, Parcelable)`.

Comment: so something liek this should work:

ConsumerObject consumer = (ConsumerObject) intent.getSerializableExtra("CONSUMER");

ConsumerObject being my POJO

Answer (score 5):

You can pass them

```
intent.putExtra(String, Serializable)
intent.putExtra(String, Parcelable)
```

Also don't forget how to get them

```
obj = intent.getParcelableExtra(String)
obj = intent.getSerializableExtra(String)
```

Better implement Parceable because it's CPU faster.